# Mediaplayer sometimes doesn't work

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

I'm running into the problem when I my play a video with my app using mediaplayer. Sometimes the video will play fine but other times there will just be a black screen. Its not the file that I'm calling the video from because I've tested on the same file and it works sometimes and sometimes doesn't. I feel this problem most commonly occurs after I have played a couple of videos. I usually get away with playing 3-4 before the problem starts. I was wondering what caused this and how I could fix it. My code is posted below.

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener{

private static final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;
SurfaceView surfaceview;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    long id = i.getExtras().getLong("id");
    String path = i.getExtras().getString("videopath");

    surfaceview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceview.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    player = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        player.reset();


        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        player.setDataSource(path);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        player.prepare();
        player.start();


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    player.setDisplay(holder);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer p) {

}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    Log.i(TAG, "THERE WAS AN ERROR");
    return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to know exactly what the problem is.

A couple of things to try:

- Make sure you are calling `.release()` in `onPause()`. This just ensures resources are released appropriately. You will need to reset things in `onResume()`, etc.

  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()
- Unless you really need to manipulate the surface, consider using a `VideoView`. It's not as fully featured as the `MediaPlayer` object but takes away some of the hassle of dealing with a `SurfaceView`, and manages the state for you.

  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that your implementation relies on the assumption, that the activity gets destroyed, when the media player finished.

Yet it is possible, that your activity already exists, when your intent is fired up. In that case, your application skips onCreate(), so the media player can't be initialised.

You should override the onStart() method to launch the media player.